# Find all solutions for $e^z = -2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all solutions for $e^z = -2$. And we know there is no solution.

My trivial work:

Since if we take $\ln$ both sides, we simply have $z = \ln(-2)$ which isn't defined.

But, since my work looks very trivial, I want to add more.

Thank you.

Comment: there is no integer solution, but there are complex solutions.

Comment: I have to assume that it has no solution and prove why.

Comment: Considering the tag is complex analysis, it very well does have a solution in the complex domain

Comment: then what you said is enough, assuming it's homework

Comment: Assuming it's a single variable real-value course

Comment: Please read all the comments on this page. The answer is you accepted may not lead you to learn the heart of the matter here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

$e^z = -2$

$z = \ln(-2)$

Now since $e^{i\pi} = -1$,  $\ln(-1)=i\pi$,
and since $\log_z a + \log_z b = \log_z(ab)$,

$\ln(-2) = \ln(-1) + \ln(2)$

$\ln(-2) = i\pi + \ln(2)$

$z = i\pi +\ln(2)$

Comment: $e^{i\pi} = -1$ does not imply that $\ln(-1) = i\pi$.

Comment: @Piman: You're incorrect. Do you think $e^{2\pi i}=1$ implies that $\ln(1)=2\pi i$?

Comment: The logarithm in complex domain is more subtle than its real counterpart. First of all, we have to specify its domain and then on that domain too, the function is not injective. So we must be wary of complex logarithm. See the two solutions below for the "correct" approach.

Comment: The definition of a logarithm is that when $a^x = y$ then $\log_ya=x$, since $e^{iπ}=-1$ $\ln(-1) = iπ$

Answer (score 9):

By taking the natural log of both sides, one obtains $$ z = \log(2) + i\pi(2n+1)$$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$
Try to see if you can figure out why this is so.

If it truly is for a complex analysis course the following will be helpful:
$e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^xe^{iy} = e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a solution.  I won't give it away, but I'll give you a hint:

$e^{i\pi} = -1$

So $e^z = -1$ has a solution.  Maybe you can jump from here to the solution for $e^z = -2$.

Comment: Q&A site: "I don't feel like answering your question". I understand the reason in regards to OP, but the scope of this website goes beyond that and a proper answer should be provided for those that might stumble by this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$e^z = e^x\times e^{iy}.$$
So, we would like to have $e^xe^{iy} = 2\times(-1)$.

We can write $e^{iπ} = -1$ and thus $e^xe^{iy}= 2e^{iπ}$.  Comparing real and imaginary parts on both sides gives
$$e^x = 2 \implies x = \ln 2$$
and periodicity implies $y = \pi +2n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So, $$z = x+iy = \ln 2 + i(2n+1)\pi, \qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let e^z = 2

z = ln2 + (θ+2kπ)

From e^z = e^(x+iy)

e^x . e^iy = 2

e^x(cosy+isiny)=2

e^x cosy =2

which means θ=y=0

so z= ln2 +2kπ

and because e^iπ=-1,

e^z(e^iπ)=2(-1)=-2

e^(iπ+ln2+2kπ)= -2